# Share on Facebook not accurate

Tags: php, facebook

I am having a problem on sharing my page on Facebook so I will go directly to the problem I need it ASAP. So this should be the url www.filipinogourmetchef.com/uploads/restaurant/serialkey 
 so it happens in the url it became like this 
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.filipinogourmetchef.com%2Fuploads%2Frestaurant%2Fl6rdQft2vTDNjMStap2.jpg 
I think this is the reason why my page picture is not accurate even the url.
This is how I share my website page

```
<a class="btn" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo urlencode("FGC RESTO");?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo urlencode("YES") ?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo urlencode(base_url().'Restaurants/view_restaurant/'.$r_sk); ?>&amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo urlencode(base_url().'uploads/restaurant/'.$restopic); ?>">share on facebook</a>
```